# Delphi. How To get ListViewItem visible proprty?

Tags: delphi, listview, listitem

Hi i Have a lisview with a big number of items in it(10-20k). It's virtual (OwnerData). I need to get smth Like AListItem.visible propery, not in OnDataEvent. There is MakeVisible method but no other propertie connected with visibility :( . The perfect if there is can be VisibleItems[] array(which is updated on scroll, resize and viewStyleChange). Any ideas of how i can do that?

Comment: How are you going to use it?

Comment: There is heavy background procces of loading images (they are dinamically created from other resources). I've got some kind of 1 image per sec, so i can't do it on data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: It works, thanks ListItemVisible := SendMessage(List.Handle, $1000+182{LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE}, ListItem.Index, 0)<>0;

Comment: If you don't have `LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE` message constant already defined in `CommCtrl.pas` unit, define it as `const LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE = LVM_FIRST + 182` instead of using hardcoded magical numbers.

Comment: @DimDim Yes, but now you can write it once, give it a name, and make all other uses self-documenting